# Why does OpenCV waitKey() not work when called from a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, user-interface, event-loop

I wanna kill the `while` loop in `beepsound()` when I press the <kbd>s</kbd> key on the keyboard. However, in this loop, this code can not get a key value.

However, the `if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q')` in `App()` works when I press the <kbd>q</kbd> key.

How can I solve this problem?

I want to escape the `while` loop in `beepsound()` when I press the <kbd>s</kbd> key.

```
def beepsound():
    while True:
        if beep == 1:
            while True:
                if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('s'):
                    print("you pressed the s")
                    beepupdate(0)
                    return
                else:
                    sd.Beep(2000,1000)
                    time.sleep(1)
        
def beepupdate(a):
    global beep 
    lock.acquire()
    beep = a
    lock.release()


def App():
   ...
   while True:
      ...
      if ...:
         beepupdate(1)
      .....
      if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
          break

p0=threading.Thread(target=App)
p1=threading.Thread(target=beepsound)
p0.start()
p1.start()
```

Comment: You have two `while True` in the beepsound function, that doesn't seem correct. Also breaking a loop, you use `break`.

Comment: the point is keyboard.is_pressed or waitKey are not working....

Comment: Use `while/else` then `break`

Comment: Opencv waitKey needs an opencv window with mouse focus to work. If there is no window (e.g. imshow or namedWindow) present you will neither get any waiting nor any key-presses.

Comment: since you want keyboard events in a terminal, opencv is *absolutely the wrong library*. remove it. it's wrong here.

Comment: wait... did you say that _one_ of the waitKey() calls *did work*? then you must have created an OpenCV window at some point. your [mre] does not show this. -- yes, calling this from another thread will fail. you can't do that. it all must be called from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use break instructions to go out of while True loop.

Simple example:

```
for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    if i == 3:
        break
print('Loop exited')
```

output:

```
0
1
2
3
Loop exited
```

Comment: OP clearly already knows about the `break` keyword. you missed the point of the question. the question asks about doing this when pressing a key on the keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the community! I cannot reproduce your whole problem but I guess the fix below should work.

```
def beepsound() :
    s_key_pressed = False
    while True and not s_key_pressed:
        if beep==1 :
            while True and not s_key_pressed:
                if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('s') :
                    print("you pressed the s")
                    beepupdate(0)
                    s_key_pressed = True
                    return
                else:
                    sd.Beep(2000,1000)
                    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks but,,,, not working...